# Can we access the ArcMap Image Analysis tools using Python?

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap

Esri recently added a new [Image Analysis](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009t000000m7000000) window to ArcMap - it's found under > Windows in the main toolbar:

[image]

> The Image Analysis window's Processing section simplifies the
>   experience of applying complex processing and analysis techniques to
>   layers of image and raster data in ArcMap. The tools provide one-click
>   options to apply processes, such as clipping, normalized difference
>   vegetation index (NDVI) creation, mosaicking, and exporting

[image]

**Can we access these tools using Python?**

Specifically, I want to automate the process of applying a Clip, then [adding Functions](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009t000000n1000000) to the clip, before exporting to a new layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save your functions in a [raster function template](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Saving_a_raster_function_template_from_the_layer_s_symbology/009t0000024q000000/) and apply this template to other rasters using the [Edit Raster Function](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Edit_Raster_Function/001700000163000000/) tool (Standard or Advance license needed).